# how to use host network config using docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose, redhat

I'm trying to use server(host) network setting for docker container also. I'm able to do it using docker run command but not able to do it using docker-compose.
I'm trying to achieve same behaviour as the command -

`sudo docker run -p 8001:8001 -d --network host --name container_name image_name`

using docker-compose. All the solution I found in internet are not working.

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:

    e-si:
        build: ./path/to/project
        networks : host
        ports:
            - 8001:8001
        volumes:
            - /server/location:/container/location
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode):

> Network mode. Use the same values as the docker client `--network` parameter, plus the special form `service:[service name]`.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  e-si:
    build: ./path/to/project
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - /server/location:/container/location
```